# jquery - how to load google direction widget in colorbox?

Tags: jquery, google-maps, colorbox

I have a google directions widget loaded on my page with the following code:

```
<div class="directions">
  <script src="http://www.gmodules.com/ig/ifr?url=http://hosting.gmodules.com/ig/gadgets/file/114281111391296844949/driving-directions.xml&amp;up_fromLocation=&amp;up_myLocations=<%= @meeting.location.address %>&amp;up_defaultDirectionsType=&amp;up_autoExpand=&amp;synd=open&amp;w=320&amp;h=55&amp;title=Directions+by+Google+Maps&amp;lang=en&amp;country=US&amp;border=%23ffffff%7C3px%2C1px+solid+%23999999&amp;output=js"></script>
</div>
```

The above works and looks great. Rather than making the above appear on the page, I want it to load in a colorbox when the user clicks on a link called directions. Question is: how can I get the above to open in a colorbox? Doing the following does not work:

```
$.colorbox({href:"<the http link from above>"});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Your div has no real contents and it's not clickable. You can style it using CSS, Try this http://jsfiddle.net/WAhyG/1/

Comment: Well, the script link in the div has rails code in it which might make it not load for you but it's loads fine for me. I was asking at a higher level as to how I can achieve opening a script in a colorbox.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.directions').click(function(){
    var src = $(this).find('script').attr('src');
    $.colorbox({ href: src });   
})
```

Comment: in this case color box does open but the contents failed to load as in the widget fails to load.